# React Native Lottie View Animation Play/Pause Issue

Tags: animation, react-native, lottie

I'm using React Native Lottie Wrapper to show animation on screen.
I need a functionality to play/pause/resume animation.

Here is my a part of my code:

```
...

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    progress: new Animated.Value(0)
  };
}

static navigationOptions = {
  title: "Details",
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
  },
  headerTintColor: '#fff',
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  headerTruncatedBackTitle: 'List'
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.animation.play();
}

playLottie() {
 console.log('play');
}

pauseLottie() {
  console.log('pause');
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Animation
        ref={animation => { this.animation = animation; }}
        source={require('../../../../assets/anim/balloons.json')}
        style={{height: 300, width: '100%'}}
        loop={false}
        progress={this.state.progress}
      />
      <Text>Course with id: {this.props.navigation.state.params.courseId}</Text>
        <Button 
          onPress={this.playLottie}
          title="Play Lottie"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Play video"
        />
        <Button 
          onPress={this.pauseLottie}
          title="Pause Lottie"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Pause video"
        />
     </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

...
```

The animation is playing well but I can't pause it and resume it.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

P.S. I have tried to use **this.animation** in **pauseLottie()** method but it said that is undefined.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In play and pause put setState({ progress: true }) or false.

Comment: it said that this.setState is undefined.

Comment: I set on button onPress={() => this.pauseLottie} and the error has gone but the animation is not pausing.

Comment: I posted an answer have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me it didn't work well: we have to add setValue(0), then we need to improve pause/restart to maintain the playing speed and change easing function to avoid slow re-start. Let's also add looping:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.playLottie.bind(this);
  this.pauseLottie.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    progress: new Animated.Value(0),
    pausedProgress: 0
  };
}

playLottie = () => {
  Animated.timing(this.state.progress, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: (10000 * (1 - this.state.pausedProgress)),
    easing: Easing.linear,
  }).start((value) => { 
    if (value.finished) this.restartAnimation();
  });
}

restartAnimation = () => {
  this.state.progress.setValue(0);
  this.setState({ pausedProgress: 0 });
  this.playAnimation();
}

pauseLottie = () => {
  this.state.progress.stopAnimation(this.realProgress);
}

realProgress = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  this.setState({ pausedProgress: value });
};
...
```

(Now) For me, it's working fine! Play and pause option work as expected.

Answer (score 8):

You can pause and play Lottie animation by changing the `speed` prop, where `speed={0}` puts LottieView component in pause and `speed={1}` plays it at normal speed.

Here is an example:

```
playAnimation = () => {
    this.setState({speed: 1})
}

pauseAnimation = () => {
    this.setState({speed: 0})
}

<LottieView
    source={this.state.sourceAnimation}
    speed={this.state.speed} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the state from the play/pause functions. In order to access the state of the Component, you have to bind the function to the component class:

First option in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.playLottie.bind(this);
  this.pauseLottie.bind(this);
}
```

or second option when declaring inside class use the es6 function syntax:

```
playLottie = () => {
 ...
}

pauseLottie = () => {
 ...
}
```

Inside those function call `setState` and add the value you want to set it to. In your case I would:

```
playLottie = () => {
  this.setState({ progress: true })
}

pauseLottie = () => {
  this.setState({ progress: false })
}
```

It is important you bind those two functions to your class component, because you will not be able to access component props. Thats why it is throwing you an error `setState is not a function`

Your render looks good ;)

Comment: thank you for your answer but progress true\false are not valid values. It can only be number.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Lottie animation that contains a loop you can control it all with the LottieView api built in. (if you are using a file that has the animation)

```
import Lottie from 'lottie-react-native'

const ref = useRef<AnimatedLottieView>()

const pause = () => { 
   ref.current.pause()
}

const resume = () => { 
   ref.current.resume()
}

const reset = () => { 
   ref.current.reset()
}

<Lottie
  ref={ref}
  source={source}
  resizeMode={resizeMode}
  loop={true}
  duration={duration}
  autoPlay={true}
  onAnimationFinish={onFinish}
/>
```